# How to prevent error 'Cannot destructuring...' in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

How I can prevent error 'Cannot destructuring 'field' of undefined or null' in this code:

```
const [{ field }, { field2 }] = await Promise.all([asynchronous operations...])
```

Comment: By making sure the promises resolve to objects with those properties? i.e. the first one should have `field` as property, and the second, `field2`. In your case one of the promises resolves with `undefined` or `null`. Prevent that.

Comment: @trincot in Promise.all I perform operations with DB, in one case promise returns object with this property, and in another it returns 'null'. If the promise returned 'undefined', then I would be able to use default value, but I cannot use it with 'null' value.

Comment: So what do you want to happen to your variables `field` (`field2`) when the corresponding Promise resolves to `undefined` or to `null`?

Comment: You could map `null` to `undefined` with Array#map E.G. `(await Promise.all([...])).map( x => x === null ? undefined : x )` and then use default values.

Comment: @Paulpro, that would be the vanilla JS version of my answer that escaped me. You should post it as an answer. :)

Comment: You can provide a fallback like this: `const [{ field }, { field2 }] = (await Promise.all([asynchronous operations...]) || [{}, {}])`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution using a 3rd party library ([`async-af`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-af)).

```js
const input = [Promise.resolve(null), Promise.resolve({field2: 'b'})];

(async () => {
  const [{field}, {field2}] = await AsyncAF(input).map(
    result => result != null ? result : {field: null, field2: null}
  );
  console.log(field, field2);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/async-af@7.0.10/index.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, if you *wanted* to use a default value:

```js
const input = [Promise.resolve(null), Promise.resolve({field2: 'b'})];

(async () => {
  const [{field = 'defaultValue'}, {field2 = 'defaultValue'}] = await AsyncAF(input)
    .map(result => result != null ? result : {});
  console.log(field, field2);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/async-af@7.0.10/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oops, just realized that wouldn't cover the 2nd result being null. Will have to take a longer look. Edit: OK, fixed.